# Angular checkbox check or uncheck

Tags: angularjs

Currently I'm able to check the checkbox and can update the status and at the same time I'm showing the checkbox as checked.
But while clicking again,its not get changed.

```
<md-checkbox ng-class="subtask.status === 'completed' ? 'md-checked' : ' ' " aria-label="Checkbox_{{$index+1}} checked checkbox" ng-model="subtask[$index].isChecked" ng-change="getClicked(subtask[$index],mySubtaskData._id,subtask.id)">
              <p class="subTask_{{subtask.status}}"> {{subtask.title}}</p>
</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Could you please share your controller?

Comment: $scope.getClicked = (subtask, details, subId) => {
          $scope.dataArry = {};
         if (subtask.isChecked) {
            $scope.dataArry.status = "completed";
          } else if (!subtask.isChecked) {
             subtask.selected = subtask.isChecked;
            $scope.dataArry.status = "active";
          }         
        }

Comment: have you tried using ng-click?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `$scope.dataArry = {}` in the `getClicked` function? This will change the object instance every single time $scope.getClicked is called. Is this the desired behavior?

Your naming is a little bit messy. You have a scope var called **subtask** on which you use `$index` in some cases. So, correct me if I'm wrong, but **subtask** actually has "subtasks" you access with $index and they are also called **subtask** but in the getClick function?

I'm assuming you have an `ng-repeat` there that's missing in your example. Can you also include the ng-repeat block in the example?

I've also noticed that your getClick function **sets the status property** on the `$scope.dataArry` var and yet your code on ng-class searches it on subtask.

Perhaps you wanted to write `<md-checkbox ng-class="dataArry.status"...`. It's hard to say without having more code in your example.